# Applozic Android Chat App - How to check password for a user

Tags: android, applozic

I downloaded the Applozic Chat SDK for android. Currently I found that you can login to a user account with the username and any password. I am wonder how should I implement the code to have it check if the user entered the password correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While doing Applozic Login/Register you need to set the **user.setAuthenticationTypeId(User.AuthenticationType.APPLOZIC.getValue());** and set the password .If password is incorrect you will get the exception in onFailure of UserLoginTask there you can check for this string in exception **Invalid uername/password**

```
UserLoginTask.TaskListener listener = new UserLoginTask.TaskListener() {                  

 @Override          
  public void onSuccess(RegistrationResponse registrationResponse, Context context) {           
 //After successful registration with Applozic server the callback    will come here 
 }                       

@Override             
public void onFailure(RegistrationResponse registrationResponse, Exception exception) {  
//If any failure in registration the callback  will come here 
//Here Invalid uername/password exception will be thrown if password is wrong check for the string Invalid uername/password in exception

}};                      

User user = new User();          
user.setUserId(userId); //userId it can be any unique user identifier
user.setDisplayName(displayName); //displayName is the name of the user which will be shown in chat messages
user.setEmail(email); //optional   
user.setImageLink("");//optional,pass your image link
user.setPassword(password);//Set the password
user.setAuthenticationTypeId(User.AuthenticationType.APPLOZIC.getValue());//You  need to set the Authentication type 
new UserLoginTask(user, listener, this).execute((Void) null);
```

[Applozic login sample github code link](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/applozic/mobicomkit/sample/LoginActivity.java#L262)